# Installing Caret and ggplot2 packages in R 3.2.5

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've just installed a new version of R studio 3.2.5 that way I can install packages caret and ggplot2 however I always come across the same errors and not exactly sure where the problem is.

```
library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded**
```

After this message I've `install.packages("ggplot2")`

and this shows up

```
library(ggplot2)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’**
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The message is telling you there's no package called `'Rcpp'`. Did you try `install.packages('Rcpp')`?

Comment: Yes but then this error comes up  - library(Rcpp)
Error in library(Rcpp) : there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Comment: What error do you see when you do `install.packages('Rcpp')`?

Comment: There is no problem when I install Rcpp package = package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\guest1\Documents\R\R-3.2.5\library\file17342324b5d\Rcpp’ to ‘C:\Users\guest1\Documents\R\R-3.2.5\library\Rcpp’

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\guest1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpS2vshS\downloaded_packages

However when I load it from the library the error I get is = in library(Rcpp) : there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: After I added the dependencies part this error came up                                                     "library(ggplot2)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’    "                                I've also tried to install Rcpp and this came up                                             'library(Rcpp)
Error in library(Rcpp) : there is no package called ‘Rcpp’ "                                    do you think there is anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

I have also got the same error and i tried many ways given in various solutions.
one solution which worked is

```
install.packages("stringi")
```

Then it many give errors stating some of the dependent libraries are missing.
Install those libraries, it will work.